# Can't understand why recursion depth is exceeding the limit

Tags: python, recursion

I have a program that is a simple encrypt algorithm that takes in a string and changes the letters into a new string of letters.

A function puts scrambled letters from the alphabet into the `code` table. In this function I have a `checkRepeat` function to ensure that a letter doesn't repeat. When I do this by hand (other than the random integer generation part) it makes sense but my computer doesn't like it and exceeds the 'recursion depth'.

```
from random import *;

string="Hello I am a computer";
alphTable=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
           'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x',
           'y','z'];
def checkRepeat(array,val):
    global alphTable
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if val==array[i]:
            location=randint(0,25);
            array.append(alphTable[location]);
            checkRepeat(array,val);

def makeEncryptTable():
    encryptTable=[];
    global alphTable;
    for i in range (26):
        location=randint(0,25);
        encryptTable.append(alphTable[location]);
        checkRepeat(encryptTable,encryptTable[i]);
    return encryptTable;

array1=makeEncryptTable();
print(array1);
```

Here is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brandon/Documents/CG 301/WilliamsBrandonStringEncrpytionAlgorithm.py", line 38, in <module>
    array1=makeEncryptTable();
  File "/home/brandon/Documents/CG 301/WilliamsBrandonStringEncrpytionAlgorithm.py", line 35, in makeEncryptTable
    checkRepeat(encryptTable,encryptTable[i]);
  File "/home/brandon/Documents/CG 301/WilliamsBrandonStringEncrpytionAlgorithm.py", line 27, in checkRepeat
    checkRepeat(array,val);
```

...

```
File "/home/brandon/Documents/CG 301/WilliamsBrandonStringEncrpytionAlgorithm.py", line 27, in checkRepeat
    checkRepeat(array,val);
  File "/home/brandon/Documents/CG 301/WilliamsBrandonStringEncrpytionAlgorithm.py", line 25, in checkRepeat
    location=randint(0,25);
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 218, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 194, in randrange
    return istart + self._randbelow(width)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 228, in _randbelow
    if type(random) is BuiltinMethod or type(getrandbits) is Method:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: You don't need all the extra `;`. `python != jQuery`

Comment: Why are you using recursion? `global alphTable` is also not needed

Comment: you are calling the `checkRepeat(array,val)` from the checkRepeat function itself without changing the parameters.

Comment: @Slayer - yes I know, I use them purely for me and helping me read the code. Its just a personal preference.

Comment: use `string.ascii_lowercase` instead of typing all the alphabets in a list, it would look cleaner.

Comment: If you  `print(array)` you might see a clue

Comment: A valid recursive function 1. has a base condition 2. is fed a value that incrementally approaches that base value upon each call. Does your recursive function follow these rules?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I'm not trying, but thats what the error says. I'm just a little lost about this error. also ok thank you I will change that

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI - do I do that inside the array brackets [ ] ?

Comment: @BrandonWilliams, your array grows each iteration and you are recursively calling the function on the array so eventually you hit the recursion limit, I honestly would not know where to start to fix your code, this is really not something  you should be using recursion for. Is this a task that you were assigned?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - sort of but not really, it was left as here is an overlying result that you should get, and its up to me to decide how I want to get there. It may seem a bit trivial but I want to go this path.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams, can you add what your final output for string might look like, currently you don't seem to use string at all

Comment: type `import string; alphTable = list(string.ascii_lowercase) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this very easily using the `random` and `string` libraries

```
import random
import string

encrypt_table = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
print encrypt_table
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

random.shuffle(encrypt_table)
print encrypt_table
# ['d', 'v', 'f', 't', 'c', 'r', 's', 'q', 'e', 'u', 'm', 'w', 'p', 'g', 'x', 'i', 'b', 'n', 'z', 'y', 'k', 'h', 'a', 'o', 'l', 'j']
```

Also, you don't need to end lines in python with semi-colons; it's heavily discouraged and makes your code harder to read.  You should also avoid using global variables in most cases.

Also, if you're intending to use this as a cipher, you should probably use a `dictionary` instead of a `list`.

```
cipher = {k: v for k, v in zip(string.ascii_letters, encrypt_table}
word = 'test'
encrypted = ''.join(cipher[x] for x in word)
# 'yczy'
```

Or, just use the built-in cipher tools.

```
cipher = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, encrypt_table)
string.translate('test', cipher)
# 'yczy'
```

Comment: Will this result in repeats? like if I want to to make an 'h' a 'b' than later in the string a 'm' won't be a 'b' as well?

Comment: There are no repeats.  `string.ascii_lowercase` is a string containing every lowercase letter in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkRepeat(array,val)` does not have an exit condition.

You are calling the `checkRepeat(array,val)` with the same `val` every time and it matches the first element in the array, add another element to the array and repeats the same matching the first element and appending another element.